# MVVM light snippets don't appear as live templates in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, mvvm-light

Having trouble with Resharper and the MVVM Light V5.0.2 code snippets. The snippets do not appear as live templates after installation. However they appear in the code snippet manager. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't display Visual Studio's snippets, using it's own Live Templates system, which allows more functionality (macros in the code blocks). However, the snippets are still available, either by invoking the "Insert snippet" action directly, or by typing the shortcut in the editor and hitting tab.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1

You know the shortcuts by heart. Just enter them completely and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>

### Solution 2

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to invoke old Visual Studio intellisense code completion. Then enter shortcut 'mvvm....'
Sometimes this doesn't work for me. Couldn't find out why not...

### Solution 3

I translated (i.e. mainly copy & pasted them, changed a few macros) most of the **mvvm light snippets** to **Resharper live templates** and exported the result to a .dotsettings file you can download [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/k4gcvv1uxf5ff66/MvvmLight.DotSettings)

Import them via **Visual Studio->Resharper->Tools->Templates explorer->Import**

Now you get back the comfy intellisense like behavior to work with the snippets.No warranty ;-)